# Replace a string in woocommerce_email_order_details

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, email-templates

I've set up a WooCommerce store with Germanized and everything fine so far.

Now I need to replace a string in the woocommerce_email_order_details table. Somehow the email outputs the product_name and another string, which looks like a SEO string, added directly after the product, but i can't find it anywhere... Now when a customer orders multiple products, this string is attached to every single productname, which ends up in printing lots of pages...

The output in the email looks like:

product_name article-no strange-string

**An Example:**

Tshirt(Art-No.:232941)
Some text which shouldn't be there and i want to get rid of.

All products have a name in the backend, but not that string anywhere...

But my coding skills are too bad, to find out, where i could cut that string.

On top of that, a space between the product and the article number would be nice too...

What I found out so far:

In the template "email-order-details.php" woocommerce builds a table which grabs the product name:

```
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
                <th class="td" scope="col" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>;"><?php esc_html_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
```

In the template "email-order-items.php" woocommerce builds a table with the product name too:

```
    <tr class="<?php echo esc_attr( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_class', 'order_item', $item, $order ) ); ?>">
        <td class="td" style="text-align:<?php echo esc_attr( $text_align ); ?>; vertical-align: middle; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; word-wrap:break-word;">
        <?php

        // Show title/image etc.
        if ( $show_image ) {
            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_thumbnail', $image, $item ) );
        }

        // Product name.
        echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', $item->get_name(), $item, false ) );

        // SKU.
        if ( $show_sku && $sku ) {
            echo wp_kses_post( ' (#' . $sku . ')' );
        }

        // allow other plugins to add additional product information here.
        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

        wc_display_item_meta(
            $item,
            array(
                'label_before' => '<strong class="wc-item-meta-label" style="float: ' . esc_attr( $text_align ) . '; margin-' . esc_attr( $margin_side ) . ': .25em; clear: both">',
            )
        );

        // allow other plugins to add additional product information here.
        do_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text );

        ?>
        </td>
```

So i found a snippet to adresse the order-details:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'modifyEmailText', 10, 4 );  

function modifyEmailText($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email){
    $plain_text = str_ireplace( 'Some text which shouldnt be there and i want to get rid of.', '', $plain_text );
}
```

But this snippet destroys the email, just unfiltered template will show up...

Thank you,
best regards!!!!